# Optimize the distribution parameter

Tags: python, optimization, statistics, probability

Let's consider a distribution L(t) depending on a float parameter t. 
I need to compute such a value of t that 5%-quantile of distribution L(t) equals 0.

Are there any solutions in python for this problem? The way of generating a new sample for somehow chosen t and calculating its quantile seems too slow and irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand question clearly, but you have distribution with `PDF=L(x,t)` on interval [a, b] (`a` is negative), and you want to find such `t` that integral from `a` to `0` over `x` is equal to 1/20 (5%), right ?

Looks like root finding problem to me.

```
S_a^0 L(x,t) dx - 1/20 = 0
```

In Python, function I usually use is `scipy.optimize.brentq`